# moodle plugin development and git repository

Tags: moodle

Inherited a moodle project that never had any kind of VCS, with some plugins installed from third parties, and a few modules developed in-house.

Problem is, I want to update moodle, and can't just use a brand new copy, since in moodle custom code lies within the "moodle" directory.

In other CMS/frameworks, that code would be physically separated from the core code, and you could mostly update the core files by pulling from the appropriate repo, and checking out the approriate branch (with custom code living in a different repo, and third party code either living in that repo or managed as a dependency).

Is there a way to organize custom moodle development (or downloads from third parties) so it's easy to separate "core" code from installed modules/themes?

Comment: Did you try with symlinks? Using them as plugins is not officially supported (see here: https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-48379 ), but they seem to work in some cases (relative paths could cause problems though). Official stance of Moodle is also using exclude/ignore, they discourage using symlinks, but if there's no other way for you...

Answer (score 2):

We're using the .git/info/exclude file and list there all plugins which are third-party or developed in-house.

However, Moodle has awesome documentations for handling plugins using git in general, check it out: https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Git_for_Administrators

Comment: Yes, I can exclude or ignore the plugins one by one. And each time I add a new plugin/block/theme/whatever, I need to update that file. But everything is still jumbled together, and there is no clean separation between what's core and what's not. I'm looking for organizing code so that core and custom/contrib are cleanly and easily separated (simplifying for example, having 1 repo for all my code and still handle moodle with git). And submodules kinda suck for this scenario, IMO.

Comment: Hey yivi, ok true. I wound't go for submodules either, it's normally way to complicated for the advantages provided... However, if you have many changes within the Moodle core itself, you could use git cheery pick to pull them into the core after you did the update on the main moodle branch. I don't think there is an easy way to do this. In our institution we completely prohibit changes to the Moodle Core itself.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain myself. Not changes to moodle core (those are forbidden here as well). But e.g. custom themes and blocks and core themes and blocks all exist in the same folder, so core and custom coexist. I want to have different code silos for "core" and "all the rest".

Comment: Okay, so in order to make sure I understood you correctly, you have for example within your /moodle/theme/ folder two folder, once boost (moodle core) and once yourtheme folder. Now you want to move yourtheme folder, together with other third-party plugins and own customizations to a seperate folder? Did I get this right.

Comment: Yup, Same thing with all the other custom code: we have custom blocks, custom local plugins, custom renderers, etc. All that custom code is stored "within" core folders, side-by-side with core code.

Comment: That won't be possible, as Moodle checks the folder your plugins are in. Therefore,  you need to have all plugins within their plugin-type folder according to: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Plugin_types
What you could do is move them into the /local folder, however I wouldn't recommend this, as it's probably more effort than you'll benefit from it.

Comment: I thought about moving all to local, but seemed kinda messy. If at least I could have a replicate of the necessary folders in local (blocks, auth, etc), we could have everything there and live more rationally. I guess the takeaway is that Moodle development is even less beautifil than I thought. :P

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to do this, it makes total sense that you have your custom and third-party plugins within the plugin type folders which Moodle provides. When using git to manage Moodle and its plugins it takes some effort, but you can easily do a script to update all plugins, including moodle so there is not much effort needed to maintain them. Furthermore, you could use a namespace plugintype_yourcompany_pluginname to differentiate your plugins.

Comment: IMO, it makes more sense to have separate code silos. Think magento with its code silos for core/community/local, think regular FWs using composer separating everything not "local" in the "vendor" folder, think even unix sith /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin; or even WP where you can easily separate with in plugins/themes or host wp in a different directory; etc, etc. Easily separating everything core from everything not core, simplifies upgrades & maintenenace.

Comment: True but in WP as well you'll have existing themes and plugins within your wp-content/theme wp-content/plugins folder. As moodle separates them depending on the plugin type you probably have to go for the given structure anyways... :-) It's probably the case because many plugins which are now part of Moodle Core, where once third-party plugins, so for Moodle I guess this structure makes sense.

Comment: We use git submodules to manage 40 plugins and another 20 plugins of plugins.  It takes a bit of discipline and organisation to set up in the first place, but especially where multiple developers are involved it pays off.  git has improved their submodule functionality - a git pull now often does the submodule update --init --recursive for you.  Don't expect the Moodle code structure to change any time soon - there is still a lot of legacy code like the yui javascript framework, old php, etc so just keeping the ship afloat and heading in any given direction is as much as can be expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a so smart (and elegant) way of separating custom code from a default Moodle instance, even with GIT.

In a custom Moodle instance you may have:

1. new plugins (self developed or from third parties). You can see the list of additional plugins here:
   `your_moodle_systemadmin/plugins.php?contribonly=1` (or here: `Home->Site administration->Plugins->Plugins overview`).

In case you want an upgraded version of Moodle, you install it somewhere and then install on it the list of additional plugins. I would suggest here to check if the plugins have a new available version and consider installing it.

2. Custom code (that is to say: someone made core changes on Moodle). I would here [compare the old code with the new one](http://meldmerge.org/), or, even better:
   a) compare the old customized system (MoodleOld Cust.) with a brand original old system (MoodleOld orig.)
   b) Track all the core differences in your MoodleOld Cust with some inline comments
   c) Compare MoodleOld Cust with your new system and pay attention only on differences marked by you on MoodleOld Cust.
   d) Try to report the customizations on your new system, if wanted and / or necessary.

Comment: No changes to core, thankfully. That's not something I'd enjoy having. But seems weird there isn't a more straightforward way to accomplish this, being such a run-of-the-mill scenario. :(

Comment: Yes, it's  weird. I didn't find it yet, after years working with Moodle.